# Logisim hangs in Ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk-11

Tags: openjdk

I have tried both [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/circuit/files/latest/download) download and `sudo apt install logisim` with `default-jdk` and `default-jre`. In both cases, I get a white window just after logisim finishes loading and nothing else happens. What do I do? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and dwm as window manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my window manager. I was using [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org) which does not have modern window parenting system. According to the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dwm#Fixing_misbehaving_Java_applications), you can tell the application that the window manager is able to draw the window just by adding the following line in your `.xinitrc` or other x-window starter.

```bsh
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```